RStudio silly question - is there a way to get the cursor to go to final submitted line after highlighting several?
So, this is definitely a trivial and silly question about the RStudio environment. I resisted using it for years since I started off using R on Linux.  I either use then native GUI or a text editor.  One thing I miss about it is that I would highlight a large chunk of code and hit Ctrl + R and it would run and then the cursor would go all way down to the end of where I highlights.  It also didn't terminate upon error and if there was an error higher up then you'd get a bloodbath (a blue bath) of them on the console.  I kinda prefer that.
I've been sort of corralled into the RStudio environment due to work and also the temperature of the general room, so to speak, and I am not griping about it since there are some really helpful features.
But, I was wondering if I could get that native R "behavior" to happen in RStudio?

Press the right arrow on your keyboard?

On my computer it just breaks the highlight and moves a space to the right.  Dang, I had hopes for a second...
